# C program - sum of digits without include the same digit twice

Tags: c

I do the sum of the digits like that:

```
 while(number>0)
    {
          sum+=number%TEN;
        number=number/TEN;
    }
```

but I need that if the number is (for example) 123444 so it'll include only one 4 in the sum. how can I do that?

Comment: I don't get your question..and I've read it 3x

Comment: Array of 10(9, really, since we don't care about 0) elements as flags to say if you've used that digit or not. Set it to 1 when used, 0 otherwise. Check flag before adding the digit to the sum.

Comment: the user write a number. I should do the sum of the digits but if in the number there's the same digit twice so i'll include it only once in the sum.

Comment: Does the digit have to be repeated consecutively to be excluded? What I mean is, if you had `1231` would the last 1 be included? If not, AntonH has the right idea.

Comment: no, it doesn't have to be repeated consecutively to be excluded.

Answer (score 1):

Have an array of all digits initialized to zero

```
int digits[10] = { 0 };
```

Then before adding a digit you check if `digits[that_digit]` is zero, if yes you set it to 1 and add to sum, if no keep going ...

```
while(number>0)
{
    int one = number%TEN;
    if ( ! digits[one]) {
       sum+=one;
       digits[one] = 1;
    }
    number=number/TEN;
}
```

*Edit, no array version*

Add an int initialized to 0, the bit `i` indicates if that digit `i` has already been summed.

If 1 was added, bit 1 set to 1, if 2, bit 2 set to 1 etc...

```
int bits = 0;
while(number>0)
{
    int one = number%TEN;
    if (!(bits & (1<<one))) {
       sum+=one;
       bits |= 1<<one;
    }
    number=number/TEN;
}
```

Comment: can I do it without an array?

Comment: When several identical digits are present in the number, are they *always* consecutive? E.g. 1234445, not 1234544 for instance?

Comment: no, they don't have to be consecutive. it can be 12134.

Comment: See edit [ bits version ]

Answer (score 0):

First you should put some code here whatever you tried, to give you basic idea to solve your problem I am putting simple code below.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<malloc.h>
int main()
{
        int input, digit, temp, sum = 0;
        printf("Enter Input Number :\n");
        scanf("%d",&input);
        temp = input;
        //first find how many digits are there 
        for(digit = 0 ; temp != 0 ;digit++, temp /= 10);
        //create one array equal to no of digits, use dynamic array because once you find different digits you can re-allocate memory and save some memory
        int *p = malloc(digit * sizeof(int));

        //now store all the digits in dynamic array
        p[0] =  input % 10;//1
        for(int i = 0; i < digit ;i++) {
                input /= 10;
                p[i+1] = input %10;
                if(p[i] != p[i+1])
                        sum = sum + p[i];
        }

        printf("sum of different digits : = %d \n",sum); 

        free(p);
        p = 0;

        return 0;
}
```

Explanation of this code I mentioned in comments itself, it may not work for all test case, remaining try yourself.